# No persistence provider for my EntityManager in appengine backend

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, android-studio, persistence, entitymanager

I'm using Android Studio and I've created an app engine backend with the tools provided by Android Studio. I'm trying to use JPA/Persistence in my backend module for my android application.
When I try my API to store some data I get the Exception

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at be.stece.esocomm.backendApp.EsoCommEndpoint.getEntityManager(EsoCommEndpoint.java:73)
....
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named esoCommBackendPersistence
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
```

So the problem lies somewhere with my setup or project structure. Since it can't find my persistence provider. But I can't figure out where the problem lies.

First of all in my build.gradle file of this backend module I have the dependecies:

```
  compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
  compile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.0-api', version: '1.0.0.Final'
  compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.1.7.Final'
```

Then in MyModule/src/META_INF/persistence.xml I have declared everything:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="esoCommBackendPersistence">
    <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true" />
      <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true" />
      <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine" />
      <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreEnableXGTransactions"
        value="true" />
      <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns"
        value="true" />
    </properties>
    <class>be.stece.esocomm.backendApp.NewsBean</class>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I'm not 100% sure if the persistence.xml is in the right directory. I've tried several options, like moving the META_INF folder to the /src/main folder instead of just /src. But no difference.

To create my EntityManager I use the correct Persistence name

```
public class MyEntityManagerFactory {

    private static final String PERSISTENCE_NAME = "esoCommBackendPersistence";

    private static final EntityManagerFactory emfInstance =
            Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_NAME);

    private MyEntityManagerFactory() {}

    public static EntityManagerFactory get() {
        return emfInstance;
    }

}

 private static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return MyEntityManagerFactory.get().createEntityManager(); => The error is triggered on this line
    }
```

Comment: so you have GAE/Datastore defined in persistence.xml yet seem to have Hibernate in the CLASSPATH (why?). GAE/Datastore persistence is provided by google's plugin for JPA not by Hibernate (which is for RDBMS). Where you put persistence.xml is up to you, BUT at RUNTIME it has to be in META-INF from the root of the CLASSPATH; your build mechanism defines that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I got it to work.

I removed all hibernate and use the appengine persistence as per suggestion of Neil Stockton.

```
dependencies {
  appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.8.9'
  compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.8.9'
  compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.8.9'
  compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'

    // Persistence
    compile 'org.ow2.asm:asm:4.0'
    compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jpa:3.1.3'
    compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jdo:3.1.3'
    compile 'com.google.appengine.orm:datanucleus-appengine:2.1.2'
    compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:3.1.3'
    compile 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec:1.0'
    compile 'javax.jdo:jdo-api:3.0.1'
    compile 'javax.transaction:jta:1.1'
}
```

Also now I followed the following guides to create the endpoints: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Kinds_and_identifiers